# Split git repo into another git repo with desired folders/files

Tags: git, github

I have a following git repo structure

```
.
├── cmd
│   ├── ctl
│   │   └── main.go
│   └── service
│       └── main.go
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── internal
│   ├── cmd
│   │   ├── build.go
│   │   ├── convert.go
│   │   └── root.go
│   └── util
│       ├── command.go
│       └── fileutil
│           ├── tar.go
│           └── unzip.go
├── Makefile
├── pkg
│   ├── artifact
│   │   ├── artifact.go
│   │   └── archive
│   │       ├── archive.conf
│   │       └── archive.go
│   ├── errdefs
│   │   ├── error.go
│   │   └── error_target.go
│   └── addons
│       ├── settings.go
│       └── addons.go
├── README.md
└── tests.sh
```

I would make a repo that has only following path/files

```
cmd/ctl/*
internal/cmd/*
```

and rest removed. This is the structure in the end

```
.
├── ctl
│   └── main.go
├── cmd
    ├── build.go
    ├── convert.go
    └── root.go
```

I have tried [this](https://amandawalkerbrubaker.medium.com/splitting-your-git-repo-while-maintaining-commit-history-35b9f4597514) But it is only good for a single folder. Not if you want to persist two or more folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/)

The [manual page](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html) has a detailed example section for [path based filtering](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_path_based_filtering)

In your case, you are probably looking for :

```
git filter-repo --path cmd/ctl/ --path internal/cmd/ \
        --path-rename cmd/ctl:ctl --path-rename internal/cmd:cmd
```

(not tested, test it on a clone of your repo)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Except there is a small typo git-filter-repo is single word you had a space in between in you terminal command. Can you update the comment for future

Comment: if you place any executable named `git-foo` on your `PATH`, then you can invoke it by typing `git foo`.

Comment: Is see. Thanks for clarify that up . I just pip installed the package.

Comment: ok. `git-filter-repo` is also packaged with many standard distribution tools: `apt install git-filter-repo` has been part of the regular Ubuntu packages for quite some time for example.